# CIFilter - Can't Change Name

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-animation, core-image

From Apple's [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW1), listing 4:

```
...
// create the filter and set its default values
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBloom"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

// name the filter so we can use the keypath to animate the inputIntensity
// attribute of the filter
[filter setName:@"pulseFilter"];
...
```

On the [filter setName... line I get a "No visible @interface for 'CIFilter' declares the selector 'setName:'

I see that filter was created using a filterWithName initializer so I suspect that its name is read-only.  But then why is this example in Apple's code, as well as in many other example's I've found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writeable `name` property is added via a category of [Core Animation additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CIFilter_CA_Additions/Introduction/Introduction.html) that are only present on the Mac. See the [CIFilter Animatable Properties subsection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html):

> Core Animation adds the following animatable properties to Core
>   Image’s CIFilter class. See CIFilter Core Animation Additions for more
>   information. These properties are available only on OS X.
>
> - name
> - enabled

CIFilter on iOS does have a `-name` method, but that's only for read-only access to the filter name, and there's no matching setter.

That section of the Core Animation Programming Guide that you link to above was copied and pasted from the original Mac version of the guide, and should be altered because it doesn't entirely apply to iOS.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'll file a radar.  Good to know I'm not crazy (at least this time :)

Comment: @MichaelMangold - Yeah, that copied and pasted documentation has caused more than a little bit of confusion over the years, especially when Core Image wasn't even available for iOS.

Comment: BTW I'm watching your Core Animation video now where you mention that Core Image isn't available on iOS.

Comment: @DavidH - I think you mean Core Image, not Core Animation. Core Animation has been around since Leopard and the original iPhone OS. I've clarified the above answer to indicate that I meant a settable property, which is still only present on the Mac. There's a `-name` getter on iOS, but no matching `-setName:` like on the Mac's Core Image.

Comment: @BradLarson yes, my typo! The original poster never looked at the CIFilter documentation for iOS - this is all there clearly. I never went to Mac docs (even though I did use CIFilter there a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I never saw an example of trying to change the name of a CIFilter - what you get from the filterWithName is a highly specialized object. If you look at the class documentation, it shows a method "name" that returns the name, but no property that is readwrite.

If you need a keypath to the object, then store it in a property of your class, and you can then access it via setValue:... forKeyPath:@"myClass.myIvar."

EDIT: just to be completely clear:

```
Core Image was added in iOS 5. Also the statement in the answer is not correct. Look in the CIFilter class description "name
The name of the filter.

- (NSString *)name
Return Value
A string that holds the name of the filter.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
CIFilter.h
```

Looking in CIFilter.h for iOS5.1:

```
 "- (NSString*)name __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_5_0);
```

"